# mex endpoint in WCF is returning error 400

Tags: .net, wcf

I have created a simple WCF service with the help of Microsoft documentation.
I have exposed two endpoints
 1. service endpoint (/CalculationService) and 
2. service Metadata end point (/mex)

The Service is hosted properly inside a console application and I am able to browse the service baseAddress and baseAddress?wsdl from browser.

Question here is-
When I try to browse  the endpoint /mex and /CalculationService , I get Bad request 400 error.

What is exactly getting wrong here. Find the below code for hosting application.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Step 1 of the address configuration procedure: Create a URI to serve as the base address.  
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/");
        // Step 2 of the hosting procedure: Create ServiceHost  
        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);
        try
        {
            // Step 3 of the hosting procedure: Add a service endpoint.  
            // Step 4 of the hosting procedure: Enable metadata exchange. 
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            //ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, new BasicHttpBinding(), "mex");


            // Step 5 of the hosting procedure: Start (and then stop) the service.  
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");
            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.  
            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();
        }
    }
```

I am not adding anything explicitly inside the web.config file.
Here is my web.config file for WCF service.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel> 
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>-->

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>-->    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you consume your service from client application? I think things your are trying to browse are "unbrowsable".

Comment: When I try to add service reference from Visual Studio for baseURL in the client application , I can see the service methods, but the same thing is not working for /CalculationService and /mex urls.

Comment: As there is http binding for both metadata as well as service endpoint , both the URLs should be browsable, isn't it?

Comment: This is endpoint. Something, that client app will use for connection establishment and consuming services. Again:  
Can you consume your service from client application?

Comment: Yes. I can consume the service from client application. Its totally fine, but my question is why those two endpoints (/CalculationService and /mex) are not working at all, then what is the use of specifying the endpoint address separately while creating endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Because you can have more than one endpoint in a service, that's why it is important to specify them.

And they are actually working. Metada exchange endpoint is for exchanging metada. If the client application couldn't reach this endpoint, you wouldn't be able to reference a service.

The other endpoint is exposing methods. If you are able to consume it and use its methods, then it is working as well.

Comment: Michal, I agree with you on above answer. Let me coin one more question here. As smb.HttpGetEnabled = true; already exposes metadata over http, why there is a need to create a separate endpoint for IMetadataExchange contract. Even if I don't have this /mex endpoint for the above  contract, my service is exposed on "baseaddress?wsdl" adress isn't it?

Comment: Well, I am not certain with the answer, so I will just guide to some other resource: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/08/10/wsdl-vs-mex-knockout-or-tie/ . This one shed some light when I was having similair questions.